Running python in putty (unix) IImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'. Use pip or conda to install openpyxl
I'm trying to run a python program via unix (putty).
I've been doing it for a while and it was working, but now it doesn't.
I get the following error in the log :
Model Spec ILD_Distributeur_xxx.xlsx ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/iri/local/stat-prd/infoscan/code_recensement/code_recensement_geo_retailers_prod_test.py", line 63, in <module> VGH_detailed = pd.read_excel("{}/{}".format(path,file), sheet_name="VGH_detailed", header=1) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 364, in read_excel io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1233, in __init__ self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 521, in __init__ import_optional_dependency("openpyxl") File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 118, in import_optional_dependency raise ImportError(msg) from None ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last): ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
Knowing that when I run it via jupyther I don't get this error.
Nb: I can't install the library, it's complicated. Is there an alternative?
The code is very long but here is the part that causes the problem:
`try:   
    import os
    from re import search, IGNORECASE
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import traceback
    import sys
    
        
    path = "//server/path1/" 
    list_dossier = []
    time = []
    patho = "//server/path2/"
           
    for dossier in os.listdir(path):
        
        if search( "File_name", dossier,  IGNORECASE) and search( "xlsx", dossier, IGNORECASE) and not search( "copie", dossier, IGNORECASE) and not search( "dev", dossier, IGNORECASE) and not search( "provisoire", dossier, IGNORECASE) and not search( "temporaire", dossier, IGNORECASE) :
            if "~" in dossier or "$" in dossier:
                pass
            else:
                list_dossier.append(dossier)

    for i in list_dossier:        
        pathi = "{}/{}".format(path,i)
        modification_time = os.path.getmtime(pathi)
        time.append(modification_time)

    last_time = time
    last_time.sort()
    last_time = last_time[-1]


    result = list_dossier[time.index(last_time)]
    print(result)

    file = [file]
    file = str(file[-1])


    # nous importons les feuilles VGH_detailed et Geographies
    VGH_detailed = pd.read_excel("{}/{}".format(path,file), sheet_name="VGH_detailed",  header=1)
    Geographies = pd.read_excel("{}/{}".format(path,file), sheet_name="Geographies",  header=1)

    # on declare la table 
    table = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(len(VGH_detailed)), columns=["Model","Super Folder","Folder","Level","Geography Label","ILD Code","Legacy Code","Drill Down to Store Level"])
`

Thanks for your help
I've tried changing the syntax, looking at the files, testing with the unix code, etc., but nothing works.

Can you print out the versions of Python (import sys
print(sys.version)) that are running in Jupyter and the stand-alone script, to make sure they are using the same Python environement?

use print( os.executable ) to get /full/path/to/python and check if you have the same path in all situations. You may use this path to install missing modules /full/path/to/python -m pip install openpyxl

On Jupyter: 3.9.13
On putty, there are several versions ( the versions below ) but for the code I use python 3.7 :
python3.7 /local/path/code.py
Versions in putty :
usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2-config
/usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python-config
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.6m
